# Проблема с Оператором switch при распознавании текста

Tags: java, android, android-studio, switch

Решил, сделать своего голосового помощника, но при проверки строки через switch, мне постоянно выкидывает default, уже не знаю что делать использую yandex speech kit mobile

```
package com.yandex.speechkit.recognizersample;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import ru.yandex.speechkit.Error;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.Recognition;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.Recognizer;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.RecognizerListener;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.SpeechKit;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.Synthesis;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.Vocalizer;
import ru.yandex.speechkit.VocalizerListener;

import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

/**
 * This file is a part of the samples for Yandex SpeechKit Mobile SDK.
 * <br/>
 * Version for Android © 2016 Yandex LLC.
 * <p/>
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * <br/>
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * <br/>
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
public class RecognizerSampleFragment extends Fragment implements RecognizerListener, VocalizerListener {
    private static final String API_KEY_FOR_TESTS_ONLY = "069b6659-984b-4c5f-880e-aaedcfd84102";

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView currentStatus;
    private TextView recognitionResult;
    private Vocalizer vocalizer;
    private Recognizer recognizer;

    public RecognizerSampleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SpeechKit.getInstance().configure(getContext(), API_KEY_FOR_TESTS_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button startBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
        Button startvoise = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start_say);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createAndStartRecognizer();
            }
        });
        startvoise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = recognitionResult.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                    switch (text){
                        case "ПРИВЕТ.":
                            text = "Приветствую";
                            break;
                        default:
                            text = "Я вас не понимаю";
                    }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Write smth to be vocalized!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    // Reset the current vocalizer.
                    resetVocalizer();
                    // To create a new vocalizer, specify the language, the text to be vocalized, the auto play parameter
                    // and the voice.
                    vocalizer = Vocalizer.createVocalizer(Vocalizer.Language.RUSSIAN, text, true, Vocalizer.Voice.ALYSS);
                    // Set the listener.
                    vocalizer.setListener( RecognizerSampleFragment.this);
                    // Don't forget to call start.
                    vocalizer.start();
                }
            }
        });
        Button cancelBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetRecognizer();
            }
        });

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.voice_power_bar);
        currentStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_state);
        recognitionResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        resetRecognizer();
    }
    private void resetVocalizer() {
        if (vocalizer != null) {
            vocalizer.cancel();
            vocalizer = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            return;
        }

        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            createAndStartRecognizer();
        } else {
            updateStatus("Record audio permission was not granted");
        }
    }

    private void resetRecognizer() {
        if (recognizer != null) {
            recognizer.cancel();
            recognizer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRecordingBegin(Recognizer recognizer) {
        updateStatus("Recording begin");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpeechDetected(Recognizer recognizer) {
        updateStatus("Speech detected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpeechEnds(Recognizer recognizer) {
        updateStatus("Speech ends");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRecordingDone(Recognizer recognizer) {
        updateStatus("Recording done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSoundDataRecorded(Recognizer recognizer, byte[] bytes) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPowerUpdated(Recognizer recognizer, float power) {
        updateProgress((int) (power * progressBar.getMax()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Recognizer recognizer, Recognition recognition, boolean b) {
        updateStatus("Partial results " + recognition.getBestResultText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRecognitionDone(Recognizer recognizer, Recognition recognition) {
        updateResult(recognition.getBestResultText());
        updateProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Recognizer recognizer, ru.yandex.speechkit.Error error) {
        if (error.getCode() == Error.ERROR_CANCELED) {
            updateStatus("Cancelled");
            updateProgress(0);
        } else {
            updateStatus("Error occurred " + error.getString());
            resetRecognizer();
        }
    }

    private void createAndStartRecognizer() {
        final Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, RECORD_AUDIO) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            // Reset the current recognizer.
            resetRecognizer();
            // To create a new recognizer, specify the language, the model - a scope of recognition to get the most appropriate results,
            // set the listener to handle the recognition events.
            recognizer = Recognizer.create(Recognizer.Language.RUSSIAN, Recognizer.Model.NOTES, RecognizerSampleFragment.this);
            // Don't forget to call start on the created object.
            recognizer.start();
        }
    }

    private void updateResult(String text) {
        recognitionResult.setText(text);
    }

    private void updateStatus(final String text) {
        currentStatus.setText(text);
    }

    private void updateProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSynthesisBegin(Vocalizer vocalizer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSynthesisDone(Vocalizer vocalizer, Synthesis synthesis) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayingBegin(Vocalizer vocalizer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayingDone(Vocalizer vocalizer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVocalizerError(Vocalizer vocalizer, Error error) {

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) попробуйте добавить trim(), то есть recognitionResult.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase(); 2) Вы уверены что вам всегда придет "Привет" с точкой на конце? Попробуйте вывести текст перед switch, хотя бы с помощью System.out.println, там точно приходит то что вам нужно?

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Ну debug же....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switch скорее всего использует equals для сравнения строки, в вашем случае надо проверить какая строка приходит.

Распознавание голоса может возвращать слово строчными буквами или первая буква будет заглавной...

Попробуйте использовать не `switch` а `if else` и для сравнения строк использовать `equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("ПРИВЕТ.")){
     text = "Приветствую";
}else{
     text = "Я вас не понимаю";
}
```

И тут ещё один вопрос, строка, которую вам возвращает распознаватель голоса содержит в конце точку или нет?

Comment: Точка стоит обязательно

Comment: Проверил, не работает(((

Answer (score 2):

1) Во-первых, посмотрите в дебагере или с помощью `System.out.println(text);` действительно ли вы получаете нужный текст,

2) Если строка визуально вроде бы та что вы ожидаете,  попробуйте добавить `trim()`, то есть вместо:

```
String text = recognitionResult.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
```

используете:

```
String text = recognitionResult.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase();
```

Это типичная проблема при сравнении строк в Java, когда они в дебагере/логе/консоли вроде бы выглядят правильными, но пробелы или нечитаемые символы в начале или конце строки все портят и сложно догадаться почему. Поэтому всегда стоит попробовать сделать `trim()`.